# How to fix 'android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #279: Error inflating class...' error in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, exception

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #279: Error inflating 
class PACKAGE_NAME.views.customViews.CalendarObject
```

I've searched a lot in this site but none of those problems were like mine. I think it's because this error is from my customized view, CalendarObject.

I ran my application in several phones and it worked correctly. But when I run it on an emulator PIXEL_2_XL_API_19, this error appears!

Here is my log:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #279: Error 
inflating class PACKAGE_NAME.views.customViews.CalendarObject
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:621)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:759)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at PACKAGE_NAME.views.fragments.FragmentMonthlyCalendar.onCreateView(FragmentMonthlyCalendar.java:85)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3221)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3171)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:192)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:560)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is line #85 that causes the error in java doc:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_monthly_calendar, container, 
    false);
```

And line #279 in XML file:

```
<PACKAGE_NAME.views.customViews.CalendarObject
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:text="31" />
```

Here is CalendarObject class:

```
public class CalendarObject extends AppCompatTextView {
    public static final boolean VISIBLE = true;
    public static final boolean GONE = false;

    private Paint mCirclePaint;
    private boolean mCircleVisibility, mGiftVisibility;
    private float mCircleX, mCircleY, mCircleRadius;
    private Bitmap mImage;

    public CalendarObject(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null, 0);
    }

    public CalendarObject(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs, 0);
    }

    public CalendarObject(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, 
    int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttrs) {
        mCirclePaint = new Paint();
        mCirclePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mCirclePaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), 
            R.color.alertRed));
        mCircleX = getWidth() / 6;
        mCircleY = getHeight() / 6;
        mCircleRadius = 10f;

        Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), 
            R.drawable.ic_birthday);
        mImage = drawableToBitmap(drawable);
    }

    private Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable)
            return ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() / 
            2, drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() / 2, 
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);

        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mCircleVisibility) {
            if (mCircleX == 0f || mCircleY == 0f || mCircleRadius == 0f) {
                mCircleX = getWidth() / 6;
                mCircleY = getHeight() / 6;
                mCircleRadius = 10f;
            }
            canvas.drawCircle(mCircleX, mCircleY, mCircleRadius, 
                mCirclePaint);
        }
        if (mGiftVisibility) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(mImage, (float) 5 * getWidth() / 7, 0, 
            null);
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    public void setCircleVisibility(boolean visibility) {
        mCircleVisibility = visibility;
        postInvalidate();
    }

    public boolean getCircleVisibility() {
        return mCircleVisibility;
    }

    public void setGiftVisibility(boolean visibility) {
        mGiftVisibility = visibility;
        postInvalidate();
    }

    public boolean getGiftVisibility() {
        return mGiftVisibility;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me why does this error happens on API_19 ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the complete [stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174).

Comment: what is PACKAGE_NAME.views.customViews.CalendarObject ?

Comment: PACKAGE_NAME.views.customViews.CalendarObject it is a class that I'd put the code. CalendarObject class.

Comment: Make sure the path to your custom view is correct in the xml file

Comment: It is correct. it works in other API levels.

Comment: Hmm, well, that didn't help. Are you sure that the `alertRed` color resource and the `ic_birthday` drawable are both available in API level 19? That is, do you perhaps have either only in a versioned folder under `res/`; e.g., `res/values-24/`, or something like that?

Comment: Well `alertRed` color is in the `colors.xml` file that is for all of the APIs. But `ic_birthday` is a vector that I think maybe it is not compatible for API 19? And no, I don't have any versioned folder.

Comment: So is it OK to make an 'if' block to check if user's phone is under API 21 or not?

Comment: It worked for me. Thank you a lot Mike. <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is the vector drawable `ic_birthday`, As an option use [VectorDrawableCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawableCompat) to get the `Drawable`:

```
...
//Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(),  R.drawable.ic_birthday);
Drawable drawable =  VectorDrawableCompat.create(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_birthday, null);
...
```